# How to pass type dynamically to Activator.CreateInstance(object)?

Tags: c#, activator

I am trying to implement generic solution using `Activator.CreateInstace()`

Below I have interface,

```
public interface INewReleaseValidationRule<T> where T : INewReleaseValidationEntity
{
    void Run(CtxNewRelease ctx, IEnumerable<T> entities);
    string GetMessage(string messageName, string fallbackMessage);
}

public interface INewReleaseValidationEntity
{}
```

My class `CustomerAssociation` is:

```
public class CustomerAssociation : INewReleaseValidationEntity
{
 public void Run(Context.Ctx context, IList<INewReleaseValidationEntity> entitiesObject)
    {}
}
```

Then I have view model which is also implementing `INewReleaseValidationEntity`.

```
 public class ForecastViewModel : INewReleaseValidationEntity
{

}
```

Then,

```
public partial class ValidationRule
{
public void Run(Ctx context, List<ForecastViewModel > entity)
    {
        var validation = this.GetExecutionType();
        var execution = (INewReleaseValidationRule<entity>)Activator.CreateInstance(validation);
        execution.Run(context, entity.ToArray());
    }
}
```

In above highlighted statement I am getting error.

If I use,

```
var execution = (CustomerAssociation)Activator.CreateInstance(validation);
```

then it works perfectly fine. But I want to provide the explicit type (in this case `CustomerAssociation`) dynamically.

All my explicit type (that is `CustomerAssociation`) and others will be inherited from `INewReleaseValidationRule<T>`.

If I write

`var execution = (INewReleaseValidationRule<ForecastViewModel>)Activator.CreateInstance(validation);`

then getting runtime error,

> Unable to cast object of type 'CustomerAssociation' to type 'INewReleaseValidationRule`1[ForecastEstimateViewModel]'.

Comment: `this.GetExecutionType` gets the type created by `Activator.CreateInstance`. You can't just cast it to any type, does `Validations.CustomerAssociation` belong higher up the `validation` type's inheritance chain?

Comment: A cast to a type that is determined at runtime doesn't make a lot of sense. Perhaps you should be using using reflection to invoke the Run method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit unclear from the code what the actual intent is, but you can try adjusting your validator's run method to take a generic type like this:

```
public partial class ValidationRule
{
    public void Run<T>(Ctx context, List<ForecastViewModel> entity)
        where T : class, INewReleaseValidationEntity
    {
        var execution = (T)Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        execution.Run(context, entity.ToArray());
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
new ValidationRule().Run<CustomerAssociation(context, entities);
```

Comment: almost there, should not the parameter always extends `class`. e.g. `where T : class, INewReleaseValidationEntity`? you are faster than me 30sec, damn it.

Comment: Good call. Updated.

Comment: It is not compiling, giving error @execution.Run() that T does not contain definition for Run() method.

Comment: That's because in your example your `INewReleaseValidationEntity` interface is empty. I've assumed it has the run method in there in my working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vf6RJr). I've made some other assumptions about your code in order to get it to compile without your references, but you can use this as a starting point.

Comment: @S.C. thanks your dummy solution did a great help. with some modifications I am able to achieve the needed functionality.